# How to show the optimal condition of $f(\alpha) = \frac{R^2+G^2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following function: ($\alpha>0$)
$$f(\alpha) = \frac{R^2+G^2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$$

1. It is a quadratic (in $\alpha$) over linear (in $\alpha$); therefore, it is a convex function.
2. It is a symmetric function (in $\alpha$) since any permutation in $\alpha_i$ won't change the value of this function. Ex: $\alpha_1+\alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = \alpha_2+\alpha_3 + \alpha_1$.

How to show that **the minimal $f(\alpha)$ occurs when $\alpha_i$ are equal?**

What I could do is the simplest case:

$$f(\alpha) = \frac{R^2+G^2(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2)}{2(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}$$

I don;t think $R$ will influence the result (just a constant), so we can simplify it as:

$$f(\alpha) = \frac{G^2(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2)}{2(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}$$
and it becomes:
$$f(\alpha) = \frac{G^2((\alpha_1+\alpha_2)^2-2\alpha_1\alpha_2)}{2(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)} = \frac{G^2}{2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)-G^2\frac{\alpha_1\alpha_2}{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$$

How to show the following and the general case?

Comment: Seems a simple symmetry argument will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k)$ be any optimal solution, and suppose that the values *aren't* equal.

Now consider all possible permutations of $A$: they must all obtain the same optimal value by symmetry.

Now consider the *mean* of those permutations. This mean *will* have the same value for each $\alpha_i$. The mean is a convex combination, and the function is convex, so the optimal value at this new point must be less than or equal to the value at $A$. You've just recovered an optimal solution with all equal entries.

This does *not* prove that an optimal solution exists. Nor does it prove that the *only* optimal solutions have equal entries. It just proves this: that if there *is* an optimal solution, there must be at least one with all equal entries. However, now that you've reduced it to a univariate problem, you shouldn't have difficulty establishing the optimal value, probably analytically.

If you wish to prove that solutions with unequal $\alpha_i$ do *not* exist, you'll want to show that the function is strictly convex. I'm pretty sure that's the case at least for positive $R$ and $G$.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the function to be minimized $$F= \frac{R^2+G^2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$$ consider its derivatives. They write $$\frac{dF}{d\alpha_j}=\frac{G^2 \alpha_j}{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}-\frac{R^2+G^2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\Big)^2}$$ Since the same second term appears in all derivatives, then the first term is constant which implies that, when all derivatives are equal, all the $\alpha_j$ are the same.

Pushing the calculations to the end, all derivatives will be zero when all the $\alpha$'s will be equal to $\pm\frac {R}{G \sqrt k}$ and the corrsponding value of $F$ should be $\pm\frac{G R}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the definition of $f$ from a statistical standpoint, define the average value of the $\alpha_i$'s to be $\bar\alpha= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i$.

Define the variance of the $\alpha_i$'s to be $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha_i - \bar \alpha)^2= \frac{1}{k}(\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2 - k\bar\alpha^2)$.

Then $f$ can be redefined in terms of $\bar \alpha$ and $\sigma^2$ as

$$f(\alpha) = \frac{R^2+G^2(k\sigma^2 + k\bar\alpha^2)}{2k\bar\alpha}$$
where by definition all terms in the numerator are non-negative and the denominator is positive.

For any given value of $\bar \alpha$ (or equivalently, any given value of $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i$) notice that the numerator of $f$, and hence $f$ itself, is minimized when the variance $\sigma^2$ of the $\alpha_i$'s is zero.  This happens precisely when all of the $\alpha_i$'s are equal to their mean value and hence are identical.

Under the condition that the variance is zero, $f$ could be differentiated with respect to the mean of the $\alpha_i$'s which is now just a single number $\alpha$ to find its value that further minimizes $f$ in terms of R, G, and k.

Comment: Ooh, very good.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks!